# Solving PDEs using Charpit's Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To Solve : $\displaystyle 1+p^2=qz$

I have solved this equation till auxiliary equation:
$\displaystyle \frac{dp}{-pq}=\frac{dq}{-q^2}=\frac{dz}{2p^2-qz}=\frac{dx}{2p}=\frac{dy}{z} $

```
p = ∂z/∂x
q = ∂z/∂y
```

Now, I can't think ahead ..

The given answer is: $\displaystyle \frac{z^2}{2}\pm \left\{\frac{z}{2}\sqrt{z^2-4a^2}-2a^2\log \left(z+\sqrt{z^2-4a^2}\right)\right\}=2ax+2y+b$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z,p,q) = 1 + p^2 -qz = 0  ...... (1)$

Then $F_p = 2p$,$F_q = -z$, $F_z = -q$,

Therefore the Charpit's Equations are

$\frac{dx}{2p} =\frac{dy}{-z} =\frac{dz}{2p^2-qz} =\frac{dp}{pq}=\frac{dq}{q^2}$

Then $\frac{dp}{pq} = \frac{dq}{q^2} => ln|q| = ln|p|+ln|a|$, where a is constant

$=>$ $q=ap$

From equation $(1)$  you will find the value of p then using these values and from the equation $dz=pdx +qdy$

You'll get the required complete integral.

Answer (score -1):

Let's complete Austin20's solution. Substituting $q=ap$ in $dz=pdx+qdy$, we obtain
$$
dz=p(dx+ady)=pd\xi \implies p=\frac{dz}{d\xi}\qquad(\xi:=x+ay). \tag{1}
$$
Now, let's substitute $q=ap$ in the PDE $1+p^2=qz$ and solve for $p$:
$$
1+p^2=apz \implies p=\frac{az\pm\sqrt{a^2z^2-4}}{2}. \tag{2}
$$
Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ and integrating, we obtain
$$
\frac{dz}{d\xi}=\frac{az\pm\sqrt{a^2z^2-4}}{2} \implies \xi+b=\int\frac{2\,dz}{az\pm\sqrt{a^2z^2-4}}=\int\frac{az\mp\sqrt{a^2z^2-4}}{2}dz
$$
\begin{align}
\implies 2\alpha x+2y+\beta&=\int\left(z\mp\sqrt{z^2-4\alpha^2}\right)dz \\
&=\frac{z^2}{2}\mp\left[\frac{z}{2}\sqrt{z^2-4\alpha^2}-2\alpha^2\log\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-4\alpha^2}\right)\right], \tag{3}
\end{align}
where $\alpha:=\frac{1}{a}$ and $\beta:=\frac{2b}{a}$.