# Singular solution of partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics, singular-solution

If complete integral of  differential equation
  $$ x (p^2 +q^2) = zp $$ ( p is  partial derivative of z with respect to x and q is partial derivative of z with respect to y )

Passing  through $x=0$ and  $z^2 =4y$ then envelope of  this family   passing through  $x=1$ ,$y=1 $  has

- 1) $z= -2 $
- 2) $z=2$
- 3) $z= √(2+2√2)$
- 4) $z= -√(2+2√2)$

Comment: If you could explain in what way this polynomial problem involves partial derivatives? And what solution method you are alluding to?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case, http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/misc/charpits_method_compl_int.pdf, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471972/solving-a-non-linear-partial-differential-equation-px5-4q3x26x2z-2-0, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844431/solving-pdes-using-charpits-method/2231978#2231978

Comment: Sir please tell  me what are the two charpits ratios  which can give me the solution here ?just give me hint please ?

Comment: Also consult http://www.iitg.ernet.in/natesan/courses/MA201_Lecture_Slides/Lectures-4-6.pdf

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case, a generalized form of characteristics is obtained by solving the ODE system (Lagrange-Charpit equations)
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{2px-z}
=\frac{dy}{2xq}
=\frac{dz}{x(p^2+q^2)}
=\frac{dz}{pz}
=\frac{dp}{-q^2}
=\frac{dq}{pq}
\end{align}
The last two ratios give $p^2+q^2=a^2=const.$, thus $a^2x=pz$.

The third last and last ratios give $\dfrac{dz}z=\dfrac{dq}q$ thus $$z=cq\tag{$1z$}$$ which gives $$x=\dfrac{c}{a^2}pq.\tag{$1x$}$$

Then also $\dfrac{dy}{2x}=\dfrac{dq}{p}=\dfrac{cq\,dq}{x}$ which gives $$y=\dfrac{c}{a^2}q^2+d.\tag{$1y$} $$

At this point the characteristic curve is represented as the image of the circle $p^2+q^2=a^2$.
Elimination of the partial derivatives $p,q$ implies 
$$
(ax)^2+(a(y-d))^2=z^2\tag{2}
$$
as the relation between $x,y,z$ along a characteristic curve.

---

The initial curve $x_0=0$, $y_0=\frac14z_0^2$ resp $s\mapsto(0,\frac14s^2,s)$ is part of the solution surface, thus 
$$
\dot z_0(s)=p_0(s)\dot x_0(s)+q_0(s)\dot y_0(s)
\\
\implies 1=p_0·0+q_0·\frac12z_0~~\text{ or }~~q_0z_0=2\tag{3}
$$ 
and from the original equation $$0·(p_0^2+q_0^2)=p_0z_0$$ which requires $p_0=0$ in the general case, thus $q_0^2=a^2$ and $ca^2=cq_0^2=q_0z_0=2$.

From $x=\dfrac{c}{a^2}pq=\dfrac12c^2pq$ we get
$$
4x^2=z^2(z_0^2-z^2)\tag{$4x$}
$$
Also $y_0=c+d$ so that 
$$
y=\frac{z^2}{2}+y_0-\frac{z_0^2}2=\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z_0^2}4\tag{$4y$}
$$

---

Thus to find the values on the characteristic curve through $x=1=y$ one needs to solve the system
$$
4=z_0^2z^2-z^4,\\
4=2z^2-z_0^2.
$$
for $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution. Our starting point is the complete integral of the PDE, derived by Lutz Lehmann:
$$
z^2=a^2[x^2+(y-b)^2]. \tag{1}
$$
The intersection of the surface $(1)$ with the plane $x=0$ is the pair of lines $z=\pm a(y-b)$. Now consider the tangent line to the curve $x=0, z^2=4y$ at the point $(0,y_0,\sqrt{4y_0})\,(y_0>0)$:
$$
z-\sqrt{4y_0}=z_y(y_0)(y-y_0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y_0}}(y-y_0)\implies 
z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y_0}}(y+y_0). \tag{2}
$$
Comparing $(2)$ with $z=a(y-b)$, we conclude that the condition for the surface $(1)$ to be tangent to the curve $x=0, z^2=4y$ is$^{(*)}$
$$
(a,b)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y_0}},-y_0\right) \implies b=-\frac{1}{a^2}. \tag{3}
$$
Substituting $(3)$ in $(1)$, we obtain the family
$$
z^2=a^2\left[x^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{a^2}\right)^2\right]. \tag{4}
$$
To find the envelope of this family, we eliminate $a$ between $(4)$ and the equation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left\{z^2-a^2\left[x^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{a^2}\right)^2\right]\right\}=0
$$
$$
\implies -2a\left[x^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{a^2}\right)^2\right]
+\frac{4}{a}\left(y+\frac{1}{a^2}\right)=0. \tag{5}
$$
It follows from $(4)$ and $(5)$ that
$$
-\frac{2z^2}{a}+\frac{4}{a}\left(y+\frac{1}{a^2}\right)=0 \implies
\frac{1}{a^2}=\frac{z^2}{2}-y, \tag{6}
$$
which, substituted in $(4)$, yields
$$
z^2\left(\frac{z^2}{2}-y\right)=x^2+\frac{z^4}{4} \implies 
z^2\left(\frac{z^2}{4}-y\right)=x^2. \tag{7}
$$
Solving $(7)$ for $z$ we obtain
$$
z=\pm\sqrt{2\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}, \tag{8}
$$
which yields $z(1,1)=\pm\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}$.

---

$^{(*)}$ The same relationship between $a$ and $b$ is obtained if we require that $z=-a(y-b)$ is tangent to the negative branch of the curve $z^2=4y$ $($i.e., $z=-\sqrt{4y}).$

---

*Addendum*

Eq. $(7)$ also can be derived from Eqs. $(4x)$ and $(4y)$ of Lutz Lehmann's answer:
$$
(4x)\implies z_0^2=\frac{4x^2}{z^2}+z^2\quad\text{and}\quad
(4y)\implies z_0^2=2z^2-4y,
$$
hence
$$
\frac{4x^2}{z^2}+z^2=2z^2-4y \implies z^2\left(\frac{z^2}{4}-y\right)=x^2.
$$