# Find the complete integral of the partial differential equation and deduce the solution which passes through the curve

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the complete integral of the partial differential equation $(p^2 + q^2)x = pz$ and
deduce the solution which passes through the curve $x = 0, z^2 = 4y$.

I am able to find the complete solution which is :
$z^2=a^2x^2+(ay+b)^2$ where $a$ and $b$ are some arbitrary constant. But I am not able to find the particular solution. Finding particular solution will require eliminating $a$ and $b$ but I am still getting one of the constant in my solution.

Comment: $(4y)^2=0^2a^2+(ay+b)^2$ what are $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants we get when we solve the partial diff eqn using Charpit's Method

Comment: Then what is your problem ?

Comment: The solution containing $a$ and $b$ is general solution. I need the particular solution which passes through the given curve. Particular solutions shouldn't have arbitrary constants. I am not able to eliminate these $a$ and $b$. Pls read the ques again.

Comment: No, you don't have to eliminate $a$ and $b$. You have to find the numerical values of $a$ and $b$ and to put these values into the general solution. To find the values of $a$ and $b$, please read again my first comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular solution of partial differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328283/singular-solution-of-partial-differential-equation)